# NSOpenPanel error: NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:: nil value

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsopenpanel

I get this error when choosing a file in NSOpenPanel.

Im am using xCode 6.1.1 and Yosemite.

```
2015-02-19 21:21:11.396 Sagssystem[2239:56373] NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:: nil value
2015-02-19 21:21:11.399 Sagssystem[2239:56373] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8bb9450c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8edb976e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8bb943bd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff860ba5a7 -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:] + 129
    4   FinderKit                           0x00007fff8d345e88 -[FI_TColumnPreviewPropertyTaggingTokenFieldController viewLoaded] + 183
    5   FinderKit                           0x00007fff8d21a371 -[FI_TViewController awakeFromNib] + 106
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8baa259f -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 223
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff89e4d90d -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1216
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a02a342 -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 677
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a029f92 -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 143
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a029287 -[NSViewController loadView] + 272
    11  FinderKit                           0x00007fff8d21a41a -[FI_TViewController loadView] + 98
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff89fa85e7 -[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff89fa8551 -[NSViewController view] + 30
    14  FinderKit                           0x00007fff8d347a5e -[FI_TColumnPreviewController initCommon] + 61
    15  FinderKit                           0x00007fff8d21a2a7 -[FI_TViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] + 59
    16  FinderKit                           0x00007fff8d2d2c3e -[FI_TColumnViewController browser:previewViewControllerForLeafItem:] + 288
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a2da31c -[NSBrowser _hasLeafViewControllerForItem:] + 156
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a2c8fbf -[NSBrowser _isExpandableItem:] + 51
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a2d1bb1 -[NSBrowser _doClickAndQueueSendingOfAction:] + 277
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a2d13ff -[NSBrowser doClick:] + 384
    21  FinderKit                           0x00007fff8d2c921f -[FI_TColumnView doClick:] + 142
    22  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff8d69fcd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a078671 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 452
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a08e006 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a13e173 -[NSTableView _sendAction:to:row:column:] + 90
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a13caa6 -[NSTableView mouseDown:] + 6506
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a2e1216 -[NSBrowserTableView mouseDown:] + 195
    28  FinderKit                           0x00007fff8d2c355e -[FI_TBrowserTableView mouseDown:] + 693
    29  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a5ddcf0 -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 13331
    30  AppKit                              0x00007fff89f83b14 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 468
    31  AppKit                              0x00007fff89f807f1 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4183
    32  AppKit                              0x00007fff89ea9e08 -[NSApplication run] + 711
    33  AppKit                              0x00007fff89e24e64 NSApplicationMain + 1832
    34  Sagssystem                          0x0000000100045e62 main + 34
    35  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8380a5c9 start + 1
)
```

I call NSOpenPanel with this code:

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    NSArray * fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"png",@"jpg",@"jpeg",@"gif",@"pdf",nil];
    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];

    [panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
    [panel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
    [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES]; // yes if more than one dir is allowed

    [panel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.view.window completionHandler: ^(NSInteger result) {
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            for (NSURL *fileURL in [panel URLs]) {

            }

            return;
        } else {
            [self dismissController:self];
        }
    }];
```

The error appears first when I choose a file.
The app does not crash and I do get the filenames.

Hope someone can help :)